# Headphones not detected on Ubuntu 15.04 on the Alienware 15

Tags: headphones, alienware

I am trying to get my headphones to get detected with my Ubuntu OS on the Alienware 15, but without any luck.
Did anybody come across such issue? I am completely clueless.

Thanks for your help!

/* Edit */

- The headphones are generic, no model is listed on them.
  I will state that they work on my phone, and on my Windows machine, without any problems.
- I have tried to modify my alsa config files, but no luck there (as listed in here http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/)
- Here is a screenshot of my sound settings:

  [image]

as you can see, the headphones are not detected.

Comment: What brand/model are your headphones? What have you tried? We need more information to help you, please update your question with all relevant information and a screenshot of `sound settings` >> `output` page.

Comment: I'v updated my question above, if you have any pointers or things that you would suggest that I check, just let me know, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me... :)

- In Terminal enter command: `alsamixer`
- An ASCI UI will open, use arrows keys to find the item; "**HP/speaker Auto Detect**". It will say "**Off**" next to it.
- Press the <kbd>M</kbd> key on your keyboard and the "Off" tag will **disappear**.
- Re-plug your headphones. (in my M14X R2 it worked in **MIDDLE** jack output)
- Enjoy!

Comment: This totally worked for me! Had to press F6 and select the Intel PCH first. I've had my Alienware 15 for almost a year and never could get headphones working on it; I'd just assumed the drivers weren't supported. :)